# Text based rpg javascript practice project

Tags: javascript

I was told making a game would be a good way to learn how to use javascript properly so I have started a game in which thus far the player is prompted to create a hero, and then assign attributes to it based on its hero type(magerouge, necromancer, warlock, or shaman) however when I get to the point of assigning attributes it always says the user picked a necromancer no matter what class he actually chose. So in short something is wrong with my function called "defaultAssign". I hope i am posting this question properly, if i am posting incorrectly please let me know so I can try to fix it, this is my first question. Here is my code:

```
var heroArray = [];

var yourHero ="";

var hero = {
characterType:"",
Damage:0,
Health:0,
Mana:0,
ManaRegenRate:0,
HealthRegenRate:0,
SpecialSkills:[]
};

var mainMenu = function(){

var nameCheck = prompt("What is your Character's Name?").toUpperCase() ;
    for( var i = 0;i <= heroArray.length ; i++){

         if (nameCheck === heroArray[i]){
                alert("We have found your hero change this string later");
                runGame(heroArray[i]);  
            }


            else{

            alert("You Must Create a Champion");
        var heroName = prompt("What Will You Name Your Sorcerer!").toUpperCase;
            characterCreator(heroName);
        /*use a loop with a regular expression here to check if the name is avalible, if it is countinue, if not
         prompt the user for another name
        */
            }
        /*  run "gameSave" for particular hero
        Run the main Game function and print to the console:
        "Ah yes "+yourHerosNameHere+"," +hisOrHer+" tale echoes far and wide. We last spoke of his journey to"
        +insertCurrentCityHere+" where "+heOrShe+" "mostRecentAction"." 

        */  
        }
    }

var characterCreator = function(yourHero){
yourHero = Object.create(hero);
yourHero.characterType = prompt("Choose your Character Type:\n"+ 
    "MageRouge\n"+
    "Warlock\n"+
    "Shaman\n"+
    "Necromancer").toUpperCase;
    defaultAssign(yourHero.characterType)
}

function defaultAssign(playersType){


for (var j = 0 ; j <= 3 ; j++){
    if (playersType === "MAGEROUGE"){

        yourHero.Damage=25;
        yourHero.Health=50;
        yourHero.Mana=15;
        yourHero.ManaRegenRate=1;
        yourHero.HealthRegenRate=0.4;
        yourHero.SpecialSkills=[["pickpocket",],["sneak",],["lockpick",]];

        alert("Ahha a powerful Magerouge, choose your skills emphasis wisely,"
        +" it could determine your Destiny...");
        skillAssigner(yourHero);
        break;  
    }
    if(playersType === "WARLOCK"){

        yourHero.Damage=50;
        yourHero.Health=50;
        yourHero.Mana=25;
        yourHero.ManaRegenRate=0.6;
        yourHero.HealthRegenRate=0.3;
        yourHero.SpecialSkills=[["summonDemon",0],["bindDemon",0],["portal",0],["illusion",0]];

        alert("Ahha a powerful Warlock, choose your skills emphasis wisely,"
        +"it could determine your Destiny...");
        skillAssigner(yourHero);
        break;
    }

    if(playersType === "SHAMAN"){

        yourHero.Damage=40;
        yourHero.Health=50;
        yourHero.Mana=30;
        yourHero.ManaRegenRate=0;
        yourHero.HealthRegenRate=0.6;
        yourHero.SpecialSkills=[["weatherControl",0],["heal",0],["astralProjection",0]]

        alert("Ahha a powerful Shaman choose your skills emphasis wisely,"
        +"it could determine your Destiny...");
        skillAssigner(yourHero);
        break;  
    }

    else if(playersType === "NECROMANCER") {

        yourHero.Damage=60;
        yourHero.Health=50;
        yourHero.Mana=20;
        yourHero.ManaRegenRate=0.8;
        yourHero.HealthRegenRate=0.4;
        yourHero.SpecialSkills=[["raiseDead",0],["petrify",0],["soulSap",0]];

        alert("Ahha a powerful Necromancer choose your skills emphasis wisely,"
        +"it could determine your Destiny...");

        skillAssigner(yourHero);

        break;

        }

}   

}
/*
create an array of hometowns for the main character to choose from

*/


function skillAssigner(yourHero){

for (var s = 0;s<3;s++){
var p = 0;  
while( p < 10 ){
    var n = prompt("How many points will you spend on "+yourHero.SpecialSkills[s]+"?");
    yourHero.SpecialSkills[s][1] = n;   
    p +=n;
}
}
}



mainMenu();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `else` on the line where it checks if the player's type is a Necromancer. It is not necessary.

The `for` loop is not necessary inside the function `defaultAssign` (and with its removal, nor are the `break`s.)

Finally, `toUpperCase` is a function so you must invoke it with parentheses, `toUpperCase()`.

Resolving these issues gets your code to work.

You should work on formatting your code (or get an editor that does it for you) to increase its readability-- this will help you find errors.

Comment: Tip: You can use the "Tidy Up" functionality of [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to do code formatting for you. I use it all the time before pasting code into StackOverflow.

Comment: @Arash if you found the answer useful, you can click the green checkmark to denote it as the "accepted" answer, which increases your accept percentage.

Comment: Aha! i was trying to upvote it but my reputation was too low, thanks!